# How to get the path information from a Node in TRzShellTree?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I have a `TRzShellTree` control (by Ray Konopka from the popular Konopka Signature VCL Controls 7.0 available in GetIt).

I iterate through the nodes of the `TRzShellTree` control to append some specific information to each Node's text, retrieved from the Node's folder path :

```
for Node in RzShellTree1.Items do
begin
  //Node.FullPath? How to get the FULL PATH of the Node?
  Node.Text := Node.Text + GetNodeInfoFromNodePath(Node);
end;
```

However, I need the full path from each Node to get that information. Looking at the `TRzShellTree` methods, there seems to be no way to get a node's full path.

So how can I get the full path from each Node?

Answer (score 0):

There IS a method to get the RELATIVE path from a Node:

```
var RelativePath := RzShellTree1.PathFromNode(Node);
```

You then could easily get the full path for each node by extracting the `BaseFolder` path from the `RzShellTree1.BaseFolder` property. But how to do that? The `TRzShellTree.BaseFolder` property is of type `TRzShellLocator`. You then can concatenate the path from `RzShellTree1.BaseFolder.PathName` with the `RelativePath` variable to get the Node's full path:

```
var ThisBasePath := System.SysUtils.IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(RzShellTree1.BaseFolder.PathName));
for Node in RzShellTree1.Items do
begin
  var ThisNodeRelativePath := RzShellTree1.PathFromNode(Node);
  var ThisNodeFullPath := ThisBasePath + ThisNodeRelativePath;
  if System.SysUtils.DirectoryExists(ThisNodeFullPath) then
    CodeSite.Send('ThisNodeFullPath', ThisNodeFullPath);
end;
```

However, if you change the `Node.Text` inside this Loop, then nested subfolders in the tree will be excluded from the `DirectoryExists` condition because `TRzShellTree` obviously calculates `PathFromNode` from the nodes down the tree. In this case, it is better to use a downwards loop:

```
for var i := RzShellTree1.Items.Count - 1 downto 1 do
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish by modifying the node text for each file. The TRzShellTree (and TRzShellList) controls provide access to the Windows Shell space. The nodes represent the items in that space. It almost sounds like you want to have a standard tree view control that you just populate with the files from a specified directory. You may have better luck using the System.IOUtils functionality to iterate over the files you are interested and populating the tree view manually. Then you would be able to populate each node the way you want. The TRzShellTree (and TRzShellList) are designed to mimic the functionality of Windows Explorer and provide the file operations supported in those controls.

Comment: Ray, I use the `TRzShellTree` in an application for a special purpose: To show the user the number of specific files in each folder: https://www.screencast.com/t/Q6qM9DoX

Comment: In this sense, it would be useful to get the path information from a node Independently from its `Node.Text`.

Comment: Fortunately, I have now found a way to get the full path of the selected Node independently from its `Node.Text` with this code: https://www.screencast.com/t/Ir8GpZDLF4JO

Comment: Or, in a more abbreviated form: https://www.screencast.com/t/Yefhon0S11